# Configuración entorno Spring-boot en windows 10

Tags: spring-boot

Me gustaría configurar un entorno dev en mi máquina Windows 10 para que pueda crear una aplicación de Spring-boot.

He realizado los siguientes pasos:

- Descarge el archivo spring-boot-cli-1.5.6.RELEASE-bin.zip
- Lo descomprimi en mi computador.
- Configure la variable de entorno a través de la consola de windows utilizando la instrucción `set PATH=D:\spring-boot-cli-1.2.3.RELEASE\bin;%PATH%`
- Luego en la consola utilizo la instruccion `spring --version` y no arroja ningun resultado.

¿Alguien ha realizado este proceso antes?

Answer (score 0):

Me ha funcionado cuando las agregué manualmente.

```
SPRING_HOME D:\spring-boot-cli-1.2.3.RELEASE
```

y despues agregas al path

```
; %SPRING_HOME%\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo instalar Java y el compilador que mas te acomode Maven o Gradle.
Con eso solucionas cualquier problema, ya que al iniciar un proyecto añades las dependencias de spring que quieras. En tu `pom.xml` o en tu `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Para gestionar Spring boot debes utilizar un gestor de proyectos, por ejemplo [maven](https://maven.apache.org/)

Añade las variables de entorno a tu sistema Windows y ya podrás ejecutar el servicio dentro de la carpeta de tu aplicación con el comando:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Si aún así sigues queriendo que sea una aplicación ejecutable desde tu prompt del sistema, deberás crear un fichero .bat que ejecute el comando:

```
java -jar <nombre-de-fichero-jar-de-tu-aplicación-spring-boot>
```

Y añadir éste a tu variable de entorno PATH.